# Print in another row if subrpeort has many records

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a fastreprot with a subreport.
When record count of subrpeort is greater than five, I want to print rest of the subreport records in another detaildata record (in main report).
The detail data band cannot stretch because it's a label and size is per-defined.

I'm trying something like this:

```
var
  TwoRows: boolean;                                                 

procedure MasterDataSubOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent); //Sub Report                         
begin                
  if not TwoRows then
    exit;
      
  if DetailData1.RowNo = 1 then
  begin

  end;
    
  if DetailData1.RowNo = 2 then
  begin              
      MasterDataSub.DataSet.next;         
      MasterDataSub.DataSet.next;
      MasterDataSub.DataSet.next;
      MasterDataSub.DataSet.next;
      MasterDataSub.DataSet.next;
  end;  
end;

procedure DetailData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);   //Main Report                                 
begin
  TwoRows := false;                           
  if MasterDataSub.DataSet.RecordCount > 5 then
  begin              
    DetailData1.RowCount := 2;
    TwoRows := true;                            
  end                
  else
    DetailData1.RowCount := 1;                                          
end;
```

But RowNo is not defined.
How to get RowNo?